# Does locks in JAVA guarantee wake up order

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, deadlock

Hi I need to handle locking multiple resources in my program, e.g. :

```
-- Start --
Thread-1 : Lock on Res_A
Thread-2 : Lock on Res_B
Thread-3 : Lock on Res_C, Lock/Wait on Res_A(1st), Lock/Wait on Res_B(1st)
Thread-4 : Lock/Wait on Res_B(2nd), Lock/Wait on Res_C(1st)
```

My question goes, if Thread-2 finishes and releases the lock on Res_B, my understanding is both Thread-3 and Thread-4 may get the lock as they both have been waiting to acquire it. This can be guided by the fairness policy to say the longest waiting thread should get the lock, but ultimately no guarantee.

**Question:** If I want to enforce the order the waiting Threads to get the lock according to FIFO, does JAVA already has this kind of queue like lock in standard library? Otherwise can you provide a 3rd party library of such lock or a simple implementation if one has to implement his own.

Comment: Have you looked at what's inside `java.util.concurrent.locks`?

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, they have ReentranLock, ReentranReadWriteLock and StampedLock.

Comment: Okay, have you had a **better** look inside that package. You seem to know the classes, that's good. Do you know how the classes work? Especially the fairness policy.

Comment: @Kayaman yes I read this http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples/ But none of them has the queuing property I need.

Comment: Sure they do, you analphabet. What do you think the threads do while a lock is being used? They queue to acquire it. With the fairness policy set, you can even control it a little bit. However your example is complete bogus. You're talking about "locking" and "queueing". You better do some more reading before you jump into this thing, you don't seem to understand how locks work, and that's a really bad thing if you're supposed to make sure there are no deadlocks.

Comment: @Kayaman I use queue instead of trylock or lock to deliberately say I want this queuing property. My understanding is those threads waiting on a lock may not be waken up on the same order they first try to lock, even with fairness. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That doesn't matter though. To prevent deadlocks you need to lock resources in the same order, that means `A, B, C` and `B, C` are fine, but `A, B, C` and `C, B` is not fine. The fairness policy favors the longest waiter. The queue is built into the lock.

Comment: Why do you think you need to specify who gets the lock? The fairness incurs a small performance hit, but it avoids starvation. It works just fine. You don't need to do anything special (except remember to lock in the same order) to avoid deadlocks. Certainly don't try to write your own mechanisms.

Comment: @Kayaman there is no ordering in my resources. Whatever is available and needed by the thread will be locked. I have updated my question to focus on the main point.

Comment: Then you can make up an ordering. Then you can lock those resources according to that ordering in each thread. Then you won't get deadlocks. I think you don't really understand what I'm saying, because you still are talking about nonsense. It's the simplest algorithm for preventing deadlocks. Use that. If you still don't understand, do some googling around. It's a pretty simple algorithm.

Comment: @Kayaman I respect your resource ordering is a solution. Despite my queuing lock solution work or not, efficient or not, necessary or not. Can we focus on the question without digging deep into the why? Does JAVA has FIFO lock?

Comment: Nothing that guarantees FIFO, not that I know of. But man, I sure hope you know what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Kayaman thank you. I see JAVA provides an abstract class `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`, where it specifically says it is for FIFO. I may start from there. Anyway, thanks for your input.

Comment: It is FIFO, and the fair lock usually results in FIFO operation. But it's not **guaranteed** FIFO.

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Thread-2 : Lock on Res_B
> Thread-3 : Lock on Res_C, Lock/Wait on Res_A(1st), Lock/Wait on Res_B(1st)
> Thread-4 : Lock/Wait on Res_B(2nd), Lock/Wait on Res_C(1st)
> ```

This condition can never happen unless I'm not understanding your state.  If thread-2 has a lock on `Res_B` then there is no way for thread-4 to *also* hold the lock on `Res_B` while waiting for the lock on `Res_C`.

And what is the difference between lock and lock/wait?  Either the thread is `BLOCKED` meaning that it is trying to acquire a lock that is already locked by another thread or it is `WAITING` on a monitor.

If you are mixing and matching your lock orders like this then you are flirting with deadlock.  I would consider rewriting the locked sections of code to see if you can only hold one lock at a time or at least do all multi-locks in the same order.

> Question: If I want to enforce the order the waiting Threads to get the lock according to FIFO, does JAVA already has this kind of queue like lock in standard library?

Java uses the underlying system thread libraries to implement much of the threading code.  There is nothing in the specification which guarantees the order of the threads getting notified or gaining the lock.  That said, many thread implementations use FIFO queues although they may be priority ordered.

That said, the circumstances that you have outlined can never happen.

Comment: Thanks. Lock/Wait is the new operation I am seeking that allows Threads to register themselves to certain locks (multi-allow) and be put on individual FIFO queue per lock before getting into WAIT. Thread-4 does not hold the lock on B, it registers itself as the 2nd one to be notified when Thread-2 is holding the lock on B, then after Thread-3 finishes it should get the lock on B.

Comment: Huh, can you post a list to it?  Is it a new java lock in Java9 or something?

Comment: As asked in my question, if there is nothing like that in standard library, I accept answers pointing me to 3rd party library or show pseudo code how do you implement one.